# Last day of customer activity (Python DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Customer_id Date     Turnover
1           2020.6.1 123
1           2020.6.2 434
1           2020.6.3 2656
1           2020.6.4 121
1           2020.6.5 2412421
2           2020.6.1 2312
2           2020.6.2 213
2           2020.6.3 5787
3           2020.6.1 237
3           2020.6.2 223
3           2020.6.3 999
3           2020.6.4 0
```

And I need to get the last `Date` for each customer. I feel there is must be something like `df.groupby` and `df.max()`, but I haven't still figured out here. Help, please :)

Comment: Try `df.groupby("Customer_id")["Date"].max()`?

Comment: What is the full error msg?

Comment: If the dates are YYYY.MM.DD then you can use groupby.max()

Comment: @Chris oh, no, it is okay. good! write the full answer to close this question) thanks a looot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `max`:

```
new_df = df.groupby("Customer_id")["Date"].max()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
Customer_id
1    2020.6.5
2    2020.6.3
3    2020.6.4
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

To be extra careful, use `pandas.to_datetime` beforehand, (such as to avoid `max("2020.06.10", "2020.6.1") == "2020.6.1"`):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
new_df = df.groupby("Customer_id")["Date"].max()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
Customer_id
1   2020-06-05
2   2020-06-03
3   2020-06-04
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Chris you can use `df2 = df.groupby("Customer_id")["Date"].max()` to find the max date per customer and than `df = df.join(df2, on = 'Customer_id', how = 'left', rsuffix = '_max')` to add the max date to your original df.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have your date in date fromat. Try this and improvise your codes.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"id":np.random.randint(1,5,100), "date":pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=100),"turnover": np.random.randint(1000,10000,100)})
df_req=df.sort_values('date').groupby('id').last()
```